# Postman Newman Jenkins Java integration

Tags: java, jenkins, postman, jira-rest-api, newman

I've been struggling to envision how this would work due to my lack of experience with these technologies, so I am asking here to try to get some answer.
So this is the story:

I have some postman tests(collection) which I am planning to run with Newman through Jenkins.

My collections and environments are on gitlab.
I am able through Jenkins have a job that connects to gitlab and runs certain collection and environment.

But I would like to have those postman results be sent to Jira. I am planning to have a Java project dedicated to just sending postman results to Jira.

This is the problem:

After newman runs test, where do I save this test results file? I am guessing maybe on Jenkins workspace?

And when I run those tests I want to run maybe jar file(if this is good idea) which handles results in json and sends them to Jira API.

Also do I need maven project and could you give me a hint if similar article already exists. But I haven't had luck in finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool that allows you to share dependency versions and also allow you to simplify the build process. It's up to you whether to have a maven project or a simple java program. Just use any HTTP client libraries to talk to Jira API, there are many clients available, you can even use restasured.

But as you are using postman, just write a new collection that sends result to jira from your result json

you can pass content of your json file as environment variable and then use JSON.parse(pm.enviroment.variable(yourvariable)) to get that value

to pass your json file use below method from powershell

```
> $a= Get-Content -raw .\result.json
> newman run .\test.postman_collection.json -e .\test.postman_environment.json -k -r "cli,htmlextra" --env-var data=$a
```